# A question of resizing text and max-width images

Tags: jquery, css

OK given the following code and a link if anyone needs to see full code - [here](http://twostepmedia.co.uk/tsnew):

```
<div class="features">
    <span class="overlay">
        <img src="image.png" />        
    </span>
    <p>Hey i'm text</p>
</div>


.features {
    width: 33%;
    position: relative;
    height: 380px;
}

.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.overlay img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

So when the page loads, i have the image as an overlay covering the content. When the user hovers over the image, the overlay span slides up.

My problem is, i want to make my site responsive, so when the user pulls the browser inwards, i'd like the boxes to resize accordingly equally so it stays square shaped.

The image will resize because i have put max-width: 100%; on.

The problem is the P tag inside. How can i get the P to auto resize when the boxes change dimensions.

I dont mind using jQuery or any CSS solutions.

Comment: At the moment, the `p` is just at the top left. When the window is resized, it stays at the top left. Where is the `p` supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry, i should have made it clearer, each div is going to be full with P text, not just one line. Ie, i'd like the text to be the full size of the containing div

Comment: I see - so you want the `font-size` to scale with the `div`s width?

Comment: Yup, but bearing mind that the image i'm using is square...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do what you need:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onresize = fontResize;
    function fontResize() {
        document.body.style.fontSize = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientWidth/100) + 'px';
    }
</script>
```

you might need to amend it slightly though to get it working perfectly..